# Convert map lambda to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, pandas, list-comprehension, iterable

For...

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': 1, 'b': range(4)})

def sumthis(a, b):
    return a+b

df['sum'] = list(map(lambda x, y: sumthis(x, y), [i for i in df.a], [j for j in df.b]))
```

...what is the list comprehension for?

```
list(map(lambda x, y: sumthis(x, y), [i for i in df.a], [j for j in df.b]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`:

```
df['sum'] = [sumthis(x, y) for x, y in zip(df.a, df.b)]

print (df)
   a  b  sum
0  1  0    1
1  1  1    2
2  1  2    3
3  1  3    4
```

Answer (score 2):

The list comprehensions here are unnecessary. Pandas series objects are iterable and list conversion is not required. In addition, converting a series to a list via a comprehension is inefficient. To demonstrate the latter point, you can more efficiently use [`pd.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
df['sum'] = list(map(lambda x, y: sumthis(x, y), df['a'].tolist(), df['b'].tolist()))
```

Instead, you can use a single list comprehension:

```
df['sum'] = [sumthis(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['a'], df['b'])]
```

However, where possible, you should prefer vectorised operations to take advantage of underlying NumPy arrays. In this trivial case:

```
df['sum'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```